# Strange results when using AntiXss.HtmlEncode

Tags: .net, encoding, antixsslibrary

I am trying to limit XSS attacks to a site, and am using the AntiXss Library to encode any untrusted strings before including in the response.

```
AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(_Title, False)
```

My database value looks like this - `If There's a Fire`, which after being encoded shows the html code on screen. Strangely the source code also contains the html code with amp;#39; but browsers shows it as text rather than the correct character.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because the value was being encoded twice

Answer (score 0):

First,

Properly decode previously Encode values using `WebUtility.HtmlDecode(HTMLEncodedValue);`

then, 
If you are showing values in some HTML control like table data`<td></td>`, use controlID.innerHtml 
instead of controlID.innerText.

Kindly revert with more details, if it does not help you.